# Python increasing the read speed from HDF5 file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I'm building a database to store financial data (option chains in particular).

I retrieve data daily for each trading day i.e. 5d/week or 250d/year. I do so for 300 tickers, the database is growing at a rate of 150Mb/day and so far reached 9Gb.

The data comes in a form of pandas dataframe.

I thought to use the HDF5 format and structure the file with groups for each trading day and then further branching in tickers and further "calls"/"puts" (options jargon)

Here's the code snippet to write the file, I use pd.HDFStore and a for loop through the tickers

```
db = pd.HDFStore('Database.h5')
group = c_year + '/' + c_month + '/' + c_day + '/'# Create main group from current day

for i in tickers['Symbol']:

    db.put(group + i + '/Call', data, format = 'table', append = True, data_columns = True)
```

Writing the file each trading day is slow but I came to the conclusion that this is all about retrieving the data with pandas datareader

Subsequently, I'd need the retrieve the whole database to transform it into reduced pandas dataframes for data wrangling.

Here's the code to read the *.h5 file for "calls" only, another for loop through all the dates in a 1yr lookback period

```
for i in tickers['Symbol']:

    for date in datelist(dt.date.today() - timedelta(days = 365), dt.date.today(), timedelta(days=1)):#set number of lookback days in accordance to last day of database retrieve
        g_year = str(date.year)  # Get group year
        g_month = months[date.month]  # Get group month
        g_day = str(date.day)  # Get group day
        group = '/' + g_year + '/' + g_month + '/' + g_day + '/'       

        try:
            key_value = group + i            
            calls = pd.read_hdf(filename, key = key_value + '/Call')
```

This could become painfully slow and I noticed the slowness grows exponentially with the number of tickers I'm retrieving, which makes the process useless.

For istance when I retrieved one ticker only it took 15secs but from ticker 70 to 80 it took 50mins!

Is there anything wrong with how I structred the file or anything that I can do to speed up the process?

Comment: What type is your data? If it's mainly numeric, I've  found the best performance is by separating your numeric data into numeric HDF5 datasets and your metadata into compound-type datasets. All this via `h5py` (ignoring pandas / HDFStore altogether). Then read the data into pandas to perform your manipulations as final steps.

Comment: The data is a mixture of different types i.e numerics, strings, timestamps. I'm not entirely sure that I see what you mean but given the variety of data type that wouldn't improve the situation. Thanks for your reply anyway